# How to create view in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJvts.jpg)

How do I make a view like this in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinearLayout` and `GridLayout` to achieve it. Use two `LinearLayout`, set the `android:layout_weight=1` both of them, It could divide the entire screen equally, then use `GridLayout`, add all of Awards, use `Textview` to show the awards name, use `ImageView` to show the awards image. You can set the `android:background="@drawable/back"` as the background(award shelf image) in the outside `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@drawable/back"
   >

    <GridLayout
       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="6"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     
      

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

    
         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     
    
         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="5">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

       
    
    
    </GridLayout>

     <GridLayout
        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:columnCount="6"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     
      

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

    
         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     
    
         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="5">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hamberguer1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/myicon"/>
     </LinearLayout>

       
    
    
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is running gif.

[image]

You need to write a new GridView for `shelves`. Here is code.

```
    public class BookGridView: Android.Widget.GridView
    {
        Context context;
        private Bitmap background;
        public BookGridView(Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attributeSet):base(context, attributeSet)
        {
            
            this.context = context;
            background = null;
        }


        protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
           
            int count = ChildCount;
            int top = count > 0 ? GetChildAt(0).Top : 0;

            int width = Width;
            int height = Height;

            int totalCount = this.Count;

            //If the total is 0, there is no need to calculate the height and draw the picture
            if (totalCount > 0)
            {

                //get Columns
                int numColumns = 3;
          // Calculate the row height by calculating the number of rows and height
                int rowCount = totalCount / numColumns;
                if (totalCount % numColumns != 0)
                {
                    rowCount++;
                }
                int rowHeight = height / rowCount;


                if (background == null)
                {
                    background = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources,
                            Resource.Drawable.bookshelf_layer_center);
                    background = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(background, width, rowHeight, true);
                }

                int backgroundWidth = background.Width;
                int backgroundHeight = background.Height;

                for (int y = top; y < height; y += backgroundHeight)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x += backgroundWidth)
                    {
                        canvas.DrawBitmap(background, x, y, null);
                    }
                }
            }
            base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
        }



    }
}
```

Here is running screenshot. shelves will increase by the number of awards.

[image]

I upload my demo, you can set columns of shelves by yourself.

https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/App17.zip

Comment: How to do this with a list so that the view itself understands how many shelves are needed? I would be very grateful for your help

Comment: @Divinegdk I upload my demo, you can refer to it, please do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue